# How to put translation into javascript using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, internationalization, thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf i generate a page which content some javascript.
The js is generated with thymeleaf in order to get some part of the java model into my page.

I know how to get some translation into my html using thymeleaf.

But now i want to get some of the thymeleaf translation into my generated js in order to centralize my translation effort.

Ideally i'd like to have a `window.messages` variable which would contains all my translated messages. This var would be initialized in the genrated js script.

Any reference on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
var window.messages = /*[[#{MESSAGE_FILE_TEXT}]]*/
```

or

```
var window.messages = /*[[${TEXT_FROM_CONTROLER}]]*/
```

Reference to documentation on [script inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)

Comment: Ok that's only possibility.
Can we define all messages all in one batch ? I mean affecting a list of key using selected translation ?